# Eclipse startup exception (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in ChooseWorkspaceData.writePersistedData)

Tags: java, eclipse, indexoutofboundsexception

Just installed eclipse 3.8, it gives me a exception everytime i select a workspace.
I tried clearing the metadata directory but still no use.
I am new to eclipse and dont understand much of its configurations.

```
!SESSION 2013-09-26 11:57:16.290 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130131-0800
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-09-26 11:57:33.364
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at         org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceData.writePersistedData(ChooseWorkspaceData.java:225)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:251)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

My config:

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Thu Jan 31 09:47:12 EST 2013
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=SDKProfile
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=M20130131-0800
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.v20120914-163612.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
```

Comment: If the instalation is new, and you don't care about configurations of it, I'd just remove it completly, and download it again

Comment: Re-setting the workspace

Answer (score 7):

Goto Eclipse Folder and Try deleting

```
/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs
```

It Will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Eclipse installation directory and edit the sub file `/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`.

There should be an entry `RECENT_WORKSPACES_PROTOCOL=3` set it to 0 (instead of 3). Restart Eclipse, chose your Workspace and start. Eclipse should start correctly again.

Comment: Where would I find this file if I had STS for Mac?