# An error occured while opening STS . msg: see the log file at C:\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\configuration\1481178515487.log

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Error msg showing on log file "C:\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\configuration\1481178515487.log"

```
  !SESSION 2016-12-07 23:54:03.704 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.7.3.201602251025-RELEASE-e46
java.version=1.8.0_77
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-12-07 23:54:07.979
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3485)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3441)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.lambda$7(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:377)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createUniqueWorkspaceNameMap(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createRecentWorkspacesComposite(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createDialogArea(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

not really sure what exactly the problem is, if any body have any idea ,it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023367/eclipse-startup-exception-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-choosewor

Comment: Thanks Imran, shared link helped me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change your jdk1.7 to jdk1.8 version for solve this problem

Comment: Can you give some specific indication what exact bugfix in 1.8 solved the OPs problem?